# Angularfire ERROR in 'firebase/auth' and 'firebase/firestore' in Angular 16.2.0

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I've using Angularfire in an Angular project and when updating the Angular version to 16.2.0 'firebase/auth' and 'firebase/firestore' threw several errors. Then I did a clean install and the same thing happened as soon as I installed `@angular/fire`.

Version info
**Angular**: 16.2.0

**Firebase**: 10.4.0

**AngularFire**: 7.6.1

**SO**: Windows 10

**Dependencies**:

```json
"dependencies": { 
   "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
   "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.6", 
   "@angular/common": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/core": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1", 
   "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/material": "^16.2.6", 
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0", 
   "@angular/router": "^16.2.0", 
   "@ngrx/effects": "^16.2.0", 
   "@ngrx/entity": "^16.2.0", 
   "@ngrx/store": "^16.2.0", 
   "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.2.0", 
   "firebase": "^10.4.0",  
   "rxjs": "~7.8.0", 
   "tslib": "^2.3.0", 
   "zone.js": "~0.13.0" },
```

**AppModule**

```ts
imports: [    
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,     
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
   EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
   StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),     
   provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),     
   provideAuth(() => getAuth()),     
   provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),     
   provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),   
],
```

**Error**:

```
 ./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:28:22-40 - Error: export 'onAuthStateChanged' (imported as 'onAuthStateChanged') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:41:22-38 - Error: export 'onIdTokenChanged' (imported as 'onIdTokenChanged') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:54:23-33 - Error: export 'getIdToken' (imported as 'getIdToken') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:69:22-32 - Error: export 'onSnapshot' (imported as 'onSnapshot')
was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:184:39-47 - Error: export 'refEqual' (imported as 'refEqual') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:189:47-55 - Error: export 'refEqual' (imported as 'refEqual') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:203:39-47 - Error: export 'refEqual' (imported as 'refEqual') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:280:17-25 - Error: export 'refEqual' (imported as 'refEqual') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:290:19-27 - Error: export 'refEqual' (imported as 'refEqual') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:358:14-32 - Error: export 'getCountFromServer' (imported as 'getCountFromServer') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (module has no exports)
```

To verify the cause of the problem, I performed an installation on a clean project and the error appeared again. As soon as I uninstall `@angular/fire` the issue disappears. If I reinstall the package, the error remains.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire angular/fire supports firebase 9. I guess the problem is how you import and initialze firebase. show your appModule imports

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Also check [ask].

Answer (score 1):

this is how it should look like:
"firebase": "^9.16.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",

note that according to angular/fire docs 7.6 supports firebase 9

```
//Firebase
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAnalytics, getAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { provideMessaging, getMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { provideStorage, getStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
mports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    //Firebase
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), //work around for fireauth https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3079
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    AngularFireStorageModule,
```

Comment: ```typescript
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    AngularFireStorageModule
  ],
```

The error persists.

Comment: Error:
```./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:28:22-40 - Error: export 'onAuthStateChanged' (imported as 'onAuthStateChanged') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:41:22-38 - Error: export 'onIdTokenChanged' (imported as 'onIdTokenChanged') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/rxfire/auth/index.esm.js:54:23-33 - Error: export 'getIdToken' (imported as 'getIdToken') was not found in 'firebase/auth' (module has no exports)

 ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, and sorry for not formatting the code.

Comment: not sure I guess firebase 10 is the problem, try to downgrade to 9

Comment: In versions before to `Angular 16.2` it works normally for me.